# How to debug client side JavaScript and server side using Nodeclipse and node express

Tags: node.js, eclipse, debugging, nodeclipse

I try to find away to debug client side javascript which run on the browser,   together with the server side which runs on the node-express.
now i like it to be done all together in [Nodeclipse](http://www.nodeclipse.org/). 
i manage to debug the server side using remote debug only , which is OK solution .
but now how can i debug the client side also ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your browser functionality, e.g. debug within Google Chrome.